# Preload thumbnail while GIF is processing

Tags: html, css, load, gif

I have a website which loads a 10-20MB GIF. While this time, the user have to wait until it's processed completely.

Now i got the idea to show a thumbnail of the first image in the GIF, while the real GIF is processing in background.

Currently I'm loading the GIF with the following Code.

```
html { 
  background: url(<?= DataSource::getCurrentTimeLapsePath() ?>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Is it possible to optimize/extend this with the thumbnail-idea?

```
<?= DataSource::getCurrentTimeLapsePath() ?>
```

This code returns the current Timelapse-GIF path.

Comment: It is always a good plan to work with a thumbnail when you know it will take time to load. This way you let the users decide whether they want to wait or not. This will make preloading not even required. Animated stuff is usually only once or twice funny to watch (think of returning visitors).

Comment: @RenevanderLende as mentioned above, these GIFs are Timelapse 'videos', which are updated all 30 minutes. So there is no risk the users could get bored. But how should i resolve my problem with loading the thumbnail?

Comment: It all depends on the graphic tools you are using, but I'm guessing you can have those save a thumbnail of the file or save the **gif** as **jpeg** and resize it to the required thumb with/height, but that a tools questions. I think a three-stage `background` replacement would be nice: **thumbnail** / **loader-message** / **gif** (if I were a viewer of your gifs)